# Codeigniter - multiple database connections

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a problem with multiple db connections at Codeigniter. At my database.php i configured two databases.

```
$active_group = 'cms';
$active_record = FALSE;
     $db['cms']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['cms']['username'] = 'yoloo_cms';
    $db['cms']['password'] = 'password'; 
    $db['cms']['database'] = 'yoloo_cms'; 
    $db['cms']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['cms']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['cms']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['cms']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['cms']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['cms']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['cms']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['cms']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['cms']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['cms']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['cms']['stricton'] = FALSE;

    $db['hazeleger']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['hazeleger']['username'] = 'yoloo_websites';
    $db['hazeleger']['password'] = 'password2'; 
    $db['hazeleger']['database'] = 'yoloo_hazeleger'; 
    $db['hazeleger']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['hazeleger']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['hazeleger']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['hazeleger']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['hazeleger']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['hazeleger']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['hazeleger']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['hazeleger']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['hazeleger']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['hazeleger']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['hazeleger']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

At my model i use this when i want to connect to a other db than the usual one:

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database('hazeleger',TRUE);
}
```

But at all time codeigniter connects to cms. When i remove

```
$active_group = 'cms';
$active_record = FALSE;
```

Codeingiter gives an error. When i tried this

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $db2 = $this->load->database('hazeleger',TRUE);
}

function test()
{
      $query  = "SELECT * FROM cms_modules";
      $result = $db2->db->query($query);
      return $db2->result();
}
```

It gives an error. Variabele db2 does not exist. 
I just want to choose, at every model, wich db i want to connect to.
But is doesn,t work. Does somebody know, how i can work with different databases 
at models.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to save the variable $db2 as a class field. The you can access $this->db2 ...

Comment: No problem (: If you want you can mark my answer as "correct".

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have most probably set in /application/config/autoload.php
that the database library is automatically loaded/created.

Open autoload.php and look for this line:

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Remove 'database' from the array and save. Now it should be working in your controllers as intended.

Answer (score 1):

for future visitors' reference, the load would be along these lines:

```
$this->db2 = $this->load->database('hazeleger',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change db2 class

```
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM cms_modules";
    $result = $this->db2->query($query);
    return result();
```