# CodeIgniter how to connect multi database using database.php for first connection and Model for second connection

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have many database connection
i have primary connection in the database.php file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and i have many more connections ..
but i must to config another connections using [***Model***]

can i pass parameters to database.php?

or can i put like this code in Model

```
$db['xxx']['hostname'] = 'xxx';
$db['xxx']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['xxx']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['xxx']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['xxx']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['xxx']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['xxx']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['xxx']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['xxx']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['xxx']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['xxx']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['xxx']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['xxx']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['xxx']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['xxx']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$this->load->database('xxx', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually define the other db connections in the database.php (as you have it above) then in the model you can call to it like:

```
$this->xxx_db = $this->load->database('xxx', true); 
$this->xxx_db->set($params);
$sql = $this->xxx_db->insert('table_name');
```

Doing it this way keeps all the connections in one place - its easier to maintain.

You may also want to see this question: [Multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619711/multiple-database-connections).  I'm not exactly clear on what problem you are having.

Comment: i want to use datamapper also